# Activity listener

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to open new activity as i click at my list item.
here is my code for main java class. please help me.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView myLV;
private String[] stringArray;
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
public Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    stringArray = new String[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = "String" + i;

    }

    myLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);

    MyAdapter adp = new MyAdapter(this, stringArray);
    myLV.setAdapter(adp);
}


private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity, String[] items){
        super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, items);
        inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 10;
        }

    }
}
```

if i change public class `MainActivity` extends `Activity` to `ListActivity` then my application crashes and show unfortunately stopped working error. I really don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you that's what you want:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View view ) {
        Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class );
        startActivity(newActivityIntent); 
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView myLV;
private String[] stringArray;
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
public Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
stringArray = new String[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    stringArray[i] = "String" + i;

}

myLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);

MyAdapter adp = new MyAdapter(this, stringArray);
myLV.setAdapter(adp);

myLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //Your code by position item...
        }
    });
}


private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] items){
    super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, items);
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
      getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_twee, parent, false);
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return 10;
}

}
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the layout of a `ListActivity` you still can with `setContentView()` method from `Activity`. As long as there is a `ListView` called `@android:id/list` somewhere in your `View`. The `ListActivity` will still work.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969386/what-are-the-differences-between-extending-activity-and-extending-listactivity)